# Python : Why this scripts gets very slow after some point of time?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

I am running the below script to extract ip addresses from file f for domains in file g. It is worth to mention that they are 11 files in the path and each have about 800 million lines (each file f). In this script I am loading file g in a dictionary d in the memory and then I am comparing lines of file f, with the items in the dictionary d, if there, I check if the bl_date in d is between dates in f, then write it to another dictionary dns_dic. Here is how my script looks like:

```
path = '/data/data/2014*.M.mtbl.A.1'

def process_file(file):
    start = time()
    dns_dic=defaultdict(set)
    d = defaultdict(set)
    filename =file.split('/')[-1]
    print(file)
    g = open ('/data/data/ap2014-2dom.txt','r')
    for line in g:
        line = line.strip('\n')
        domain, bl_date= line.split('|')
        bl_date = int(bl_date)
        if domain in d:
            d[domain].add(bl_date)
        else:
            d[domain] = set([bl_date])

    print("loaded APWG in %.fs" % (time()-start))
    stat_d, stat_dt = 0, 0

    f = open(file,'r')
    with open ('/data/data/overlap_last_%s.txt' % filename,'a') as w:
        for n, line in enumerate(f):
            line=line.strip('')
            try:
                jdata = json.loads(line)
                dom = jdata.get('bailiwick')[:-1]
            except:
                pass
            if dom in d:
                stat_d += 1
                for bl_date in d.get(dom):
                    if jdata.get('time_first') <= bl_date <= jdata.get('time_last'):
                        stat_dt += 1
                        dns_dic[dom].update(jdata.get('rdata', []))

        for domain,ips in dns_dic.items():
            for ip in ips:
                w.write('%s|%s\n' % (domain,ip))
                w.flush()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    files_list = glob(path)
    cores = 11
    print("Using %d cores" % cores)
    pp = Pool(processes=cores)
    pp.imap_unordered(process_file, files_list)
    pp.close()
    pp.join()
```

Here is file f:

```
{"bailiwick":"ou.ac.","time_last": 1493687431,"time_first": 1393687431,"rdata": ["50.21.180.100"]}
{"bailiwick": "ow.ac.","time_last": 1395267335,"time_first": 1395267335,"rdata": ["50.21.180.100"]}
{"bailiwick":"ox.ac.","time_last": 1399742959,"time_first": 1393639617,"rdata": ["65.254.35.122", "216.180.224.42"]}
```

Here is file g:

```
ou.ac|1407101455
ox.ac|1399553282
ox.ac|1300084462
ox.ac|1400243222
```

Expected result:

```
ou.ac|["50.21.180.100"]
ox.ac|["65.254.35.122", "216.180.224.42"]
```

Can somebody help me find out why at some point of time the script become really slow although memory usage is all the time about 400 MG.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are opening the full file at once, instead of line by line?

Comment: If you mean file g, yes because I am loading it once in a dictionary (d) and then I compare file f , line by line to this dictionary d.

Comment: Which one is your big file?

Comment: files in the path, then ones that I am opening as f.

Comment: Why not open f line by line with `readline()`?

Comment: @user5061 A loop over a file object returns one line at a time only.

Comment: `my_opened_file.readline()` is an iterator. Cant the code be adapted? 
Wouldnt `for n, line in enumerate(f.readline()):` work?

Comment: @user5061 it can but what is the advantage over what I am doing now?

Comment: what's the content of file w?

Comment: @miraculixx that is only for writing the results

Comment: just to make sure, does process_file work fine if you call it directly on one file, i.e. in the main thread?

Comment: Why are you calling `w.flush()` after each write? This is causing tons of superfluous system calls. Do you really need real-time file writing? I'd just avoid calling `w.flush()` and just make sure that the file `w` is properly closed.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it doesn't change the overall computational complexity, I would start with avoiding redundant dict lookup operations. For instance, instead of

```
if domain in d:
    d[domain].add(bl_date)
else:
    d[domain] = set([bl_date])
```

you might want to do

```
d.setdefault(domain, set()).add(bl_date)
```

in order to perform one lookup instead of two. But actually, it seems like a `set` is not the perfect choice for storing a domain's access timestamps. If you used lists instead, you could sort each domain's timestamps before you start matching them to the session data from `f`. That way, you would simply compare each session's fields `time_last` and `time_first` to the first and last element in the domain's timestamp list to determine if the IP addresses are to be put into `dns_dic[dom]`.

In general, you are doing a lot of unnecessary work in the `for bl_date in d.get(dom):` loop. At least, at the first `bl_date` that lies between the  `time_last` and `time_first` fields, you should terminate the loop. Depending on the length of `g`, this might be your bottleneck.

Comment: re the bottleneck, computationally this is in O(n * max(d)), where n is the number of input records in file f, and max(d) is the maximal number of entries per domain. So indeed, I agree this is a potential bottleneck. Other than the system running out of CPU or memory resources in general.

Comment: The computation also includes a number of dictionary lookups with complexity _O_ (log d), resulting in _T_ = _O_ (n d log d) = _O_ (n log d!), if I am not mistaken. As I proposed, we could reach at least _O_ (n log d). So the entire IP extraction will still take linearithmic time nonetheless, but there would be no worst case of d=n with _O_ (n²). Does that seem about right?

Comment: dict lookups are O(1) according to https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity, but yes if d=n => O(n^2)

Comment: Note: `d` is a `defaultdict(set)`. In otherwords you can just do `d[domain].add(bl_date)` and this is exactly equivalent to `d.setdefault(domain, set()).add(bl_date)` *but* it's more efficient because it avoids creating tons of empty `set`s.

Comment: @J.Katzwinkel  the reason why I am doing all these lookups for different bl_date in d.get(dom) is that I need the ip address for each different time stamp (assuming that it might change). That is why your suggestion will not work here

Comment: @Bakuriu Goodpoint thanks. However, the data in dictionary d is not a large dataset , and loading it takes 17seconds per file, which is not the bottleneck.

Comment: @Mee Really? It seems like you are actually looking up the same key (`dom`) and unionize the same respective element (`set`) with the same list (the one under `rdata`) over and over, since neither `dom` nor the `rdata` node change within the `for bl_date`-loop. Or is this about the `stat_dt` counter?